# UIView without an UIViewController

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios

How and where to call `- setNeedsLayout` method of an `UIView` instance when device rotation changes without necessarily having an `UIViewController` controlling the view? Basically this could boil down to understanding view life cycle generally without a controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess some of the things that an `UIViewController` acts on behalf of the views when the user interacts with them (such as interface orientation changes, etc.) might be be handled by registering to `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` in `UIView` instead.